# wpf combo box dropdownopned

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am have three combo box on my xaml and I first one is loaded on page load , rest of them will be loaded on click event :Now I have DropDownOpened event which should load the combo and keep it open for the user to select but its hitting the statment to assign item source but then steps out of it

```
<Window x:Class="test_combo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="cbo1" Margin="40,37,328,250"  SelectionChanged="OnComboBoxChanged" />
        <ComboBox Name="cbo2" Margin="40,145,328,142" DropDownOpened="cbo2_DropDownOpened" />
        <ComboBox Name="cbo3" Margin="40,91,328,196" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     private List<string> comboList = new List<string>();
     string[] defaultParam =  { City , State ,zip} 

 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach(string s in defaultParam)
            {
                LoadCombo(s);
            }

        }


        public void LoadCombo(string name)
        {           
            comboList.Add(name);
            cbo1.ItemsSource = comboList;         
        }


        private void OnComboBoxChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string itemSel = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
            comboList.Remove(itemSel);
            MessageBox.Show(itemSel);

        }

        void cbo2_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbo2.ItemsSource = comboList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should stay open, but if it doesn't then you can just force it open by using

```
 cbo2.IsDropDownOpen = true
```